# Is it possible to use PDFsharp with .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, pdfsharp

Is it possible to use PDFsharp library with .NET Core?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can use [PdfSharpCore](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore) (not using System.Drawing). 
As long as you exclusively use it on Windows, you can also use [PdfSharpNetStandard](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpNetStandard) (using System.Drawing).

Answer (score 8):

Update (April 3, 2023):
Starting today there are new "official" PDFsharp & MigraDoc packages for .NET 6 that can also be used under Linux and other platforms.
Find the source code on GitHub or get the preview packages 6.0.0 from NuGet.

Old answer:
The "official" PDFsharp library does not yet support .NET Core, but there are "inofficial" ports to .NET Core that may or may not work as expected.

So:
**No**, PDFsharp does not work with .NET Core yet.
**Yes**, you can get third-party libraries that support the PDFsharp APIs with .NET Core.